# All Schema Columns were Removed After Removing MySql Instance

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

My MySql service was running as `MySql2`. Today, I liked to change the name to `MySql`. I started `MySql Server Instance Config Wizard` and selected the option `Remove Instance`. I then created a new instance with the name `MySql` from the same wizard.

I ran MySql Workbench and found that all my databases have no columns and when I try to select a table, an error message says:

`09:16:34   SELECT * FROM ut_db.agency_info LIMIT 0, 1000   Error Code: 1146. Table 'ut_db.agency_info' doesn't exist   0.000 sec`

I have no idea why this has happened. Does removing the instance remove databases? And if so, why are all the names of the tables are listed in MySql Workbenches navigator?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I chose the wrong `InnoDB TableSpace` path in the wizard. So choosing the path as it was before removing the instance has solved the issue.

Even though, I am not really sure why all table names of my databases are correctly listed in workbench navigator even that `InnoDB TableSpace` path is wrong!